# Possible to define a function-like macro with a variable body?

Tags: c, macros, mutex

I've been looking at the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) for defining macros and it looks like what I want isn't possible, but I figure if it is, someone here would know.

What I want to do is define this macro:

```
synchronized(x) {
  do_thing();
}
```

Which expands to:

```
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&x);
    do_thing();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&x);
}
```

In C++ I could just make a `SynchronizedBlock` object that gets the lock in its constructor and unlocks in the destructor, but I have no idea how to do it in C.

I realize I could use a function pointer in the form `synchronized(x, &myfunction);`, but my goal is to make some C code look as much like Java as possible. And yes, I know this is evil.

Comment: You really should think twice before trying to make one language look like another. A macro that looked like the syntax you're asking for would be extremely confusing to someone reading it as C.

Comment: R. is right that this might make things difficult to read, since it is not easily visible that this is a macro. I think the best is to stick to the convention that macros should be uppercase, and that the name should be really informative. I'd go for something like `MUTUALY_EXCLUDE` or so.

Comment: ^ `And yes, I know this is evil.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**EDIT**: Changed to nategoose's version

```
#define synchronized(lock) \
for (pthread_mutex_t * i_#lock = &lock; i_#lock; \
     i_#lock = NULL, pthread_mutex_unlock(i_#lock)) \
    for (pthread_mutex_lock(i_#lock); i_#lock; i_#lock = NULL)
```

And you can use it like this:

```
synchronized(x) {
    do_thing(x);
}
```

Or even without braces

```
synchronized(x)
    do_thing();
```

Comment: Very impressive.  Even the line numbers in errors would come out right.  The only real faults is that the lock argument shouldn't appear twice within the macro and you left out most of your trailing `\\`s

Comment: That is simultaneously amazing and horrifying. I never would've thought of that.

Comment: This should fix both: `#define synchronized(lock)` \
`for (pthread_mutex_t * i_ = &lock; i_; i_ = NULL)`  \
`    for (pthread_mutex_lock(i_); i_;`               \
`         pthread_mutex_unlock(i_), i_ = NULL)`

Comment: or, with a single `for()` and a check if the lock has been aquired: `#define synchronized(MUTEX) \ for(pthread_mutex_t *synchronized_mutex_ = &MUTEX; \ synchronized_mutex_ && !pthread_mutex_lock(synchronized_mutex_); \ pthread_mutex_unlock(synchronized_mutex_), synchronized_mutex_ = 0)`

Comment: +1 (well to be split with @nategoose) for a very efficient version of scope bound ressource management. Just a bit nit picking: you should have `()` around the evaluation of `lock`, and one should mention that this needs C99 because of the `for`-scope variable.

Comment: Also, this has some pitfalls concerning flow control. `break`, `continue`, `goto` and `return` may do different than the programmer expects: the first two will just terminate the `for` inside the macro, and not of an enclosing construct. The later two will jump over the `pthread_mutex_unlock`, so the lock will not be released.

Comment: @Jens: Drat!  I left out the `()` when I retyped it (trying to make it readable as a comment).  Flow control will most definitely do bad things here, which is sad because this is such a clever trick otherwise.

Comment: This version won't let you nest synchronized blocks. To fix that I changed `i_` to `i_##lock` (so `synchronized(some_lock)` expands to `for(pthread_mutex_t *i_some_lock = &some_lock; ...`. As a bonus, `synchronized(some_lock) synchronized(some_lock) {}` will cause a compiler error.

Comment: Oh, except adding `##lock` makes it not work with struct members :(

Comment: Ok, so I can make them nestable, but not with magic deadlock checking by using Santiago Lezica's code so each lock is named `_lock_ ## __COUNTER__`

Comment: @nategoose, @Brendan, there are ways to make such macros a bit more controllable for `break` etc and to have them properly nested without using extensions like `__COUNTER__`. P99 will provide a general framework for that: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__blocks_gaa864200ae44c5666b1c42cfa60836a63.html#gaa864200ae44c5666b1c42cfa60836a63

Answer (score 6):

Here's a start, but you may need to tweak it:

```
#define synchronized(lock, func, args...) do { \
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(lock)); \
    func(##args); \
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lock)); \
} while (0)
```

Use like this (unfortunately, not the Java-like syntax you wanted):

```
synchronized(x, do_thing, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: It looks like the `do ... while(0)` aren't necessary, the `{ .. }` alone work (at least with gcc). This still requires a block like `synchronized(x, function)` instead of `synchronized(x){ /* function */ }` though.

Answer (score 2):

This was the best I came up with:

```
#define synchronized(x, things) \
      do { \
           pthread_mutex_t * _lp = &(x); \
           pthread_mutex_lock(_lp);      \
           (things);                     \
           pthread_mutex_unlock(_lp);    \
      } while (0)

...

        synchronized(x,(
                          printf("hey buddy\n"),
                          a += b,
                          printf("bye buddy\n")
                        ));
```

Note that you have to use the rarely used comma operator and there are restrictions to what code can live within the (not quite java-like) synchronization code list.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question!

I looked at the other answers and liked the one using `for`. I have an improvement, if I may! GCC 4.3 introduces the **COUNTER** macro, which we can use to generate unique variable names.

```
#define CONCAT(X, Y) X##__##Y
#define CONCATWRAP(X, Y) CONCAT(X, Y)
#define UNIQUE_COUNTER(prefix) CONCATWRAP(prefix, __COUNTER__)

#define DO_MUTEX(m, counter) char counter; \
for (counter = 1, lock(m); counter == 1; --counter, unlock(m))

#define mutex(m) DO_MUTEX(m, UNIQUE_COUNTER(m))
```

Using those macros, this code...

```
mutex(my_mutex) {
    foo();
}
```

... will expand to...

```
char my_mutex__0;
for (my_mutex__0 = 1, lock(my_mutex); my_mutex__0 == 1; --my_mutex__0, unlock(m)) {
    foo();
}
```

With my_mutex__n starting in 0 and generating a new name each time its used! You can use the same technique to create monitor-like bodies of code, with a unique-but-unknown name for the mutex.

Comment: I like the approach, but it doesn't work if I pass a struct member. `synchronized(object->lock) { /*stuff*/ }` expands to `char object->lock__0; /*etc*/`, which causes a problem because lock__0 isn't a struct member.

Comment: Ahh, true =( well, the modified answer above looks better anyway, and doesn't need counters. Cheers!

Comment: Just naming the variable `_lock_ ## __COUNTER__` seems to work (and solve a problem in the other implementation).