# Replace a string in a macro variable?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

I have a macro where I pass in an argument and use that define a new variable based on the name of the input:

```
#define DO_X(x) char _do_x_var_ ## x; /* other things */
```

The problem is if I pass in a struct variable, it breaks:

```
DO_X(some_struct->thing)
```

becomes:

```
char _do_x_var_some_struct->thing; /* other things */
```

EDIT: What I want it to evaluate to is:

```
char _do_x_var_some_struct__thing; /* other things */
```

(or any valid variable name containing something similar to the input)

What I actually want is for these to work:

```
#define DO_X(x) for(char _do_x_var_ ## x; /*things*/)
DO_X(x){
    DO_X(y) {
        /*things*/
    }
}

DO_X(object->x){
    DO_X(object->y) {
        /*things*/
    }
}
```

but for these to fail:

```
#define DO_X(x) for(char _do_x_var_ ## x; /*things*/)
DO_X(x){
    DO_X(x) { // <-- multiple definition of _do_x_var_x
        /*things*/
    }
}

DO_X(object->x){
    DO_X(object->x) { // <-- multiple definition of _do_x_var_object__x (or whatever)
        /*things*/
    }
}
```

Is there some way to make this work? Maybe replacing `->` with `__` or something? I've found ways to concatenate, but not replace strings..

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the macro to give you?

Comment: 1. Are you trying to declare a classes variables outside of it? 2. This is death by macros.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I added more clarification of what I want

Comment: @Brendan: Ok.  This looks really grim!  Hiding loop constructs behind macros is almost certainly a Very Bad Idea...

Comment: You have no idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037001/possible-to-define-a-function-like-macro-with-a-variable-body

Comment: @Brendan: Please tell me this is just an experiment in "what can macros do?".  I really hope you don't actually want to do either of these things in live code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't found a way to rewrite arbitrary strings because macros cannot do that. Macros names have to be valid identifiers, which `->` is not. The C preprocessor is very limited in what it can do. You could look into `m4` for a stronger preprocessor, but you're likely headed down the wrong road.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any preprocessor mechanism to treat a struct->element parameter as two separate tokens or to autoconvert the -> to an underscore.  My suggestion is to have a separate macro, e.g. DO_X2(struct_ptr, element), which would add the "->" or "_" where needed.  Then you could use DO_X or DO_X2 as appropriate.

There is a separate problem if you plan to use these macros as indicated.  The inner for-loop can declare the exact same variable name and it will not be considered an error since they have different scope.  For example, assuming your C compiler supports declaring the iterator within the for statement like this (which I don't believe is standard behavior for C):

```
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
```

Then you could do the following and it would not be considered an error:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        ++sum;
```

The two "int i" have different scope so it should compile and execute just fine.