# How to use the block of code following the macro in the macro?

Tags: c++, scope, macros, brackets

I want to achieve something like Boost library does with its macros (e.g. just like `BOOST_FOREACH`).

This is an example of macro I currently use:

```cpp
#define LOCK_GUARD(var, block) { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ___scope__(var); block }


std::mutex mutex;

LOCK_GUARD(mutex, {
    // body...
});
```

I want known how to modify it in such a way, so I can use `LOCK_GUARD` like below:

```cpp
LOCK_GUARD(mutex)
{
    // body...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to define variables of two different types in a for loop initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866012/is-there-a-way-to-define-variables-of-two-different-types-in-a-for-loop-initiali)

Comment: @davis-herring  It has nothing to do with this question

Comment: @Jorengarenar: Doesn’t it?  The title aside, it turns out that what they wanted was to write a macro that accepted a *following* statement, which is exactly the issue here.  The question you found is a better match, though.

Comment: @DavisHerring My answer to this question doesn't even use a `for` loop. :/ I don't think it's a dupe. (Not even a dupe of what Jorengarenar linked, because that thread is about C.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: No one’s insisting that you vote for it or explain why not; inaction here implies disagreement.  I do think it’s a duplicate of the other question (and would change my close vote I could): C and C++ do share much of the same preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
Although it's for C, I think the accepted answer to [Possible to define a function-like macro with a variable body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037001/possible-to-define-a-function-like-macro-with-a-variable-body/4037214#4037214) can be of use here.

---

It's possible to create macro in such fashion by utilizing `for` loop. Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int bar;
    Foo(int bar) : bar(bar) { std::cout << 1 << std::endl; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << 3 << std::endl; }
};

#define TEST(var) \
    for (bool flag = true; flag; ) \
        for (Foo foo(var); flag; flag = false)

int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    TEST(x) {
        std::cout << foo.bar << std::endl;
    }
    // std::cout << foo.bar << std::endl; // ERROR: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope
    std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Both loops will execute if `flag` is true. First loop initializes `flag` to this value. Second loop creates object `foo`. After expansion the "body" of `TEST` becomes the body of second loop. After executing the code (everything declared inside body is should be properly destroyed by now), the second loop sets `flag` to false and therefore ends. First loops also ends and destroys the `flag`.

---

The problem is, you want to use it in multithreaded program. This approach will certainly result in data races.

Personally, I wouldn't play around with such macros, but just simply do something in such manner:

```cpp
using mutex_lock_guard = std::lock_guard<std::mutex>;


std::mutex;

void func(int x)
{
    // init...

    {
        mutex_lock_guard lock(mutex);
        // body..
    }
}
```

Or else still with macros:

```cpp
#define LOCK_GUARD(var) std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(var)

std::mutex;

void func(int x)
{
    // init...

    {
        LOCK_GUARD(mutex);
        // body..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable in an `if` condition. Then your code block can be the `if` body.

```
#define LOCK_GUARD(var) \
    if (::std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _lock_guard_(var); false) {} else
```

Note `false) {} else` instead of `true)` - it prevents `else`s in user code from attaching to the macro.

Note that using a loop (that only executes once) in place of `if` would be problematic, as `break` and `continue` would be able to interact with it, which is not good.

Comment: I tried that at first,it works inside of function,but it can't be use like this ```auto func = [] LOCK_GUARD(class_member_mutex_) {//....body}```

Comment: @aaaa I doubt there is anything what would work with such bizarre use, because `LOCK_GUARD` isn't a function.

Comment: @Jorengarenar i have half idear ,```#define LOCK_GUARD(var) { std::lock_guard<std::mutex> ___scope__(var);func() }void func``` follow this way,maybe it can be achieve,right?

Comment: @aaaa Uhh, that requirement is not in the question. Can `BOOST_FOREACH` do it? I'm pretty sure that it's either impossible or very hard, and isn't worth it anyway. I suggest settling for `[]{LOCK_GUARD(foo){...}}`.

Comment: @aaaa Please, don't make it more complicated than it already is

Comment: @aaaa I have some ideas how it could be done for captureless lambdas (involving friend-injection, which is a huge overkill for the sole purpose of getting rid of a pair of braces), but I don't think there's a way to make it work for a capturing lambda.